# Elastic Search comparing sentences with synonyms?

Tags: elasticsearch, nlp

Is there an api within elastic search to compare the following two sentences?

```
The weather is great 
The climate is good
```

The search described here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/practical-scoring-function.html doesn't work since the sentences have largely different words

Comment: What do you mean by "comparing sentences" ? What would be your expected result ?

Comment: @Pierre a similarity score between 0.5-1, hopefully, given that the two sentences are pretty much saying the same thing

Comment: Even if you can do it with elasticsearch, that might be overly complicated. Have you tried looking at other NLP libraries for text comparison ?

Comment: @Pierre-NicolasMougel ah okay...just thought ES might be a better option since it has tf-idf index and all that

Comment: with other libs, I'd need to find a way to store that index somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

The following query will give you the score that would be computed by elasticsearch.  Replace `test` by the name of your index and `field` by the name of the field using the correct analyzer.

```
{
  "script": {
    "source": "_score"
  },
  "context": "score",
  "context_setup": {
    "index": "test",
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "field": "The weather is great"
        }
    },
    "document": {
      "field": "The climate is good"
    }
  }
}
```

You will not get a score between 0.5 and 1 though. Elasticsearch is not built to perform pairwise string comparison, it is used to search within a collection of documents.

If you really want to get a score between 0.5 and 1 you will have to write a [scripted similarity function](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html)

But again, I don't think elasticsearch fit with your usecase.